# symfony 2.1 set form theme in controller

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony-2.1

Recently I used setTheme function in symfony 2.0 from  Symfony / Bridge / Twig / Extension / FormExtension.php, eg:

```
$this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->setTheme($view, $theme);
```

There is no such function in sf2.1. what's the alternative way to set form theme in controller. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked in latest source of Symfony 2.1 and seems that it is possible by:

```
$this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->renderer->setTheme($view, $theme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example of generating a template with params and setting a theme to it, from the controller.

```php
// Create the form using $this->createForm() ...
$myView = $myform->createView();
//Set the form theme
$this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->renderer->setTheme($myView, 'XBundle:path/to/theme/myTheme.html.twig');
$content = $this->renderView('XBundle:path/to/template/myTemplate.html.twig', array('templateParam1' => $myView, 'templateParam2' => $param2));
return new Response($content);
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers